# jQuery - Getting deep linking jQuery Address to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, deep-linking

I am really wanting to use the jQuery address plugin for deep linking my ajax website, but honestly, I have having a hard time understanding how to set it up.

Even the examples seem to not be clear.

Does anyone have a simple example on how to get this working?

Answer (score 7):

I went through this my first time as well.  Their documentation is poor, but it is a very good plugin.

```
$.address.init(function(event) {

}).change(function(event) {
     // all your application work should be within here.
     // each time something changes this will run
     // use the api methods to find out what is going on.
     event.path // returns the current full path from beyond /#/
     event.queryString // returns the query string ex: /#/?page=1
     event.value // returns the value /#/Home
     // These can all be accessed globally by using $.address.path(), etc         

     // usage
     // example of clicking an a tag set with the ref or href set as a div id
     // be sure to set that in the init method above
     // Shows the selected div
     $('#'+event.value).show();

});
```

Comment: Any idea how to get it working with the latest jQuery version?

Comment: No idea. Twas 4 years ago :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495507/deep-linking-with-ajax-does-not-work-with-latest-jquery-address/28594019#28594019 is the solution, but a bad style with downgrading =/