# Deep linking with Ajax does not work with latest - jquery address

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, add-on

I would like to know why **jquery address** is **not working** with the **latest jQuery** verison, or maybe what I'm doing wrong. I mean the samples given in the download folder are working well. But they are with an older jQuery verison. So I think it's broken with the latest, but I'm not quite sure.

Here some more details about that issue:https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/issues/196

The other question would be, if there is any other good addon for deep linking. I mean I would like to do everything on that site with Ajax and keeping a good structure. Already found the BBQ tool but that depricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you always should load jQuery *before* you load any jQuery plugins. In the linked example you do it in the wrong order. But regarding to the error you got you probably did it right while testing.

The next problem is that [jQuery.address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) makes use of [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) which has been removed since jQuery 1.9. In order to circumvent such issues and make migration a lot easier, there is a [jQuery migration plugin](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin) that provides missing functions from older jQuery versions.

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.address-1.5.js?strict=false&wrap=true"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing the same stuff but with an older migrate version. With that version it's working indeed. But anyways I don't think that's a good solution to use migrate. Not just because there are now so many console message, I'm able to do all this stuff without that addon meanwhile. So I gonna do it on my own. Thanks anyway. Hope fully they update that addon somewhen so that it's running without migrate somewhen.